# How can I pull in a different repo with the latest changes and keep my updates too on git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, git-clone

So the background is I have a repo which is a production repo and I have a test repo which is a clone of that production one. I have made some changes to that cloned one.

Now it's been a while and the production one has had many updates and commits since.

I want to update my cloned repo with the all the changes of the production one to the latest commit on my cloned repo but also keep some of the changes I've made on my cloned one.

How can I go about doing so?

Comment: Can you clarify and explain in more detail? Why is `fetch` and `merge` not working for you?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you added multiple remote repos? Have you tried merging, or rebasing? What's not working for you so far?

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed with two different repos. I'm not too familiar with merging and rebasing, especially with two completely separate repos

Comment: How different are they? Are they related at all? To add a remote repo use `git remote add <name> <url>`. `<name>` is usually something like `origin`, but you may already have that so use another name.

Comment: They are exactly the app when started. Now the cloned one has some changes I made, the production one has many commits and changes which I want on my repo now

Answer (score 1):

on your local machine, setup remotes to both repositories

`git remote add prod <produrl>`

`git remote add clone <cloneurl>`

do a `git fetch` to pull down all of the different branches

checkout out the cloned branch you want `git checkout -b localbranch clone/<branch>`

merge in the changes from production `git merge prod/<branch name>`

Comment: if youve already cloned the "clone" repo, you just need to setup a remote to the production repository

Comment: but if I fetch, I don't want to completely overwrite a few files from my cloned repo which I've changed

Comment: fetches will not touch local branches, just pull down changes from other repositories. a `git pull` would try to do merges for you

Comment: Right, but I still want nearly all the production changes to merge into mine. It's just about 4-5 files on my repo I want completely untouched. Cos there are other changes in random files which have probably been changed in my cloned repo which I don't mind getting overridden by the updated production one. Most importantly I want to have the latest Production code + my 4 files which I changed on my clone

Comment: right, did you try what I suggested? it pulls both repositories history and changes locally but not affecting your actual checked out branch. then you'll pull in the changes from the production branch INTO your branch. if there are conflicts, you'll need to resolve them. If you are 'worried' you're going to mess up, just create another branch (name it different) at your clone and try it out... can always just go back to your other branch if you dont like how things worked out...

Comment: OK I will give it a try now, so just to clarify if I have both repos on my local already, do I still need to do 
`git remote add prod <produrl>`
`git remote add clone <cloneurl>`


Also, when I do the `git fetch` are you referring to both the prod and clone one?

Comment: if you already have both remotes in your repo, then no, just use the remote names you have. yes, you want to git fetch both repositories. in newer versions of git, you can do `git fetch --all` to do all remotes at once

Comment: I dont quite undertand this command `git checkout -b localbranch clone/<branch>`. 
Since both branches in both repos I'm using are both `develop`. Im a bit confused how to use this.
`git merge prod/<branch name>` also for this which branch name is this referring to?

Comment: @codemaster9090 Might I suggest you to read a tutorial on Git, for example the wonderful Git Book? For instance, the chapter [Distributed Workflows](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) might be a good starting point. It never hurts to read the full book chapter by chapter.

Comment: @g19fanatic I'm getting a 'not something we can merge' when trying the git merge. I have added the remote of the prod to my cloned repo

Comment: @codemaster9090 the `checkout -b` command created a new local branch from a remote branch. I suggested doing it that way so that you didn't have to worry about about messing up your normal working branch. when you checkout the local develop branch and then merge in the `prod/develop`, it will attempt to merge the branches. So long as there is a common ancestor (which there should be based on your comments), itll either just merge right away or give you conflicts that you need to resolve. I agree with @knittl... some sort of beginners tutorial would be helpful

Comment: The OP will need to run `git fetch prod` and then `git fetch clone`, or the (rarely useful, but useful here) `git fetch --all`, or my own preferred method, `git remote update` (which means `git fetch --all`, more or less).

Answer (score -1):

As a relative newcomer to Git, I can sympathize - it can be a daunting learning curve!

One of the things to grasp about Git is that it is generally undestructive and will not readily wipe out any changes on your local version. It just looks at the changes that have been made to the upstream version **since the last time that you cloned or pulled from that upstream version**, and tries to apply those changes to your local version. So if the upstream version of file "x" has an added chunk of code, it will add the same chunk of code to the local version of file "x". But if you have added or changed a file "y" on your local version, then as long as the upstream version of "y" was not changed since the last "pull", then Git will not be interested in doing anything about that file, and will let your local updates stand.

Separate fetching and merging will not be necessary in most situations - you just need to make sure that your local version has no uncommitted changes ("git status" should not show any files), and then run "git pull". Your cloned version will probably be already implicitly linked to the upstream version - you can run "git remote -v" to check this - so you do not need to muck about with "git remote add" etc.

The only complication comes when you have made local changes at the same time as the same files on the remote version have undergone different changes. In that case running a "git pull" will evoke a response from Git telling you what you need to do. Don't panic; just read the instructions carefully and it will be simpler than you think.

This is all a great simplification of the procedure, and I am not an expert, so take what I say with a pinch of salt, but you just have to dive in and see what happens. You can almost always undo an update if it goes wrong, and as an additional reassurance, the earlier suggestion about creating a new branch to "save" your work is good.

Comment: I forgot to add that many git commands have a --dry-run option that you can stick on the end, which will help to reassure you are on the right track before you run the command for real

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).